# Intellij IDEA при сборке проекта ошибки package does not exist

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, maven

Импортировал проект в Intellij IDEA под Linux, все библиотеки maven подгрузил, но при сборке проекта получаю  подобные ошибки на все зависимости:

> Error:(4, 38) java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not
>   exist

Этот же проект под Windows в Intellij IDEA работает.
В чем причина может быть? Доступы?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringREST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringREST</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `pom` покажите в вопросе, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Добавил.

Comment: Пробовали из консоли собирать (`mvn clean verify`)? Какая версия Idea?

Comment: spring-context  нужно добавить в зависимости

Answer (score 1):

очистите проект, затем обновите его. Также проверьте наличие зависимостей в каталоге м2. Затем снова пересоберите проект.

1. Clean Maven project. Project -> RightClick -> Run As -> Maven Clean
2. Update Maven Project.
   Project -> Right Click -> Maven -> Upadte Project
   A new window will open. Select the project and check mark the "Force Update of snapshot". and then update.
3. Rebuild the project. Right click-> Run as -> Maven install

[источник](http://www.programering.com/a/MzNyMDNwATg.html)

Comment: Проблема была и есть в самом maven, точнее в настройках. По одной из инструкции добавил пути M2_HOME (я же не знал что М2 это для старой версии, а для новой нужно М3) теперь при команде mvn -version имею ошибку Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher. Все что я понял из гугла надо удалить путь М2 и установить М3 но я не знаю как удалить М2 и не могу найти информации на этот счет.